# How to broadcast path changes to all views in an AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS single-page app displaying 3 views (which are actually 3 [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)). To illustrate my question, let's assume my UI is identical to that of GMail and that my 3 views are:

- **Navigation Pane** (left) -- where GMail displays folders like "Inbox", "Drafts"...
- **Toolbar** (top right) -- where GMail displays buttons
- **Content Pane** (bottom right) -- where GMail displays messages

These 3 views need to update themselves whenever the path changes. For example:

- The Navigation Pane needs to highlight a specific item.
- The Toolbar needs to show/hide certain buttons.
- The Content Pane needs to load and display specific data from the server.

What's the best way to do this in AngularJS?

So far, I have:

1. Ruled out the use of [$routeProvider.when()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider#when) because I need to update three views, and `$routeProvider` only supports one `ngView`.
2. Created a **SERVICE** that watches the current path and uses [$rootScope.$broadcast()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) to warn the controllers that the path changed.
3. (OR, IN LIEU OF #2) Created a **CONTROLLER** that does the same as #2.
4. Caught the event broadcasted by #2 or #3 with [$scope.$on()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$on) (I do this in a view controller).

This kind of works, but I have several issues:

- The "path change" event is often broadcasted BEFORE my event listeners are in place, especially at initial page load. This is probably due to the fact that my view templates are loaded from the server and the listeners can't be set up before the templates have finished loading.
- Isn't there a more efficient/automated way to watch for path changes in AngularJS? (See my code below, it seems pretty "manual".)
- Does the code that watches for path changes belong in a SERVICE or in CONTROLLER? (I'd lean towards a service, since a controller is more to add behavior to a view.)
- How to guarantee that my views will catch the "path changed" event? Should I use an event at all? (maybe I could store the path in a service, and have my views watch the service instead?)

My code to watch for path changes (I put this in a service or in a controller):

```
var watchExpression = function() { return $location.path(); };
var listener = function(newPath, oldPath) {
    // Broadcast event on $rootScope
    $rootScope.$broadcast('PathChanged', newPath);
};
$rootScope.$watch(watchExpression, listener);
```

Then, in a view controller, I catch the event:

```
$scope.$on('PathChanged', function(event, path) {
    // Update view based on new path.
});
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Found one improvement: instead of watching path changes manually like I did, it seems better to catch the native `$locationChangeSuccess` event:  `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) { // Do something with newUrl ... });`

Comment: I ended up using neither a SERVICE nor a CONTROLLER, but a [config function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#config) which watches for the native `$locationChangeSuccess` event and updates a `$rootScope.path` variable when that event happens. Then, my path-aware controllers watch the `$rootScope.path` variable and when it changes, they use `$rootScope.pathEnv` (an custom object storing environment variables, which is recalculated whenever the path changes) to update themselves appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Your final version seems fine with the locationChangeSuccess, but for others reading this, I think you ruled out the $routeProvider too quickly. You can have one ng-view for the main content pane that changes with the path, and then other independent ("static") controllers/templates for the navigation pane and toolbar.

Now to listen to route changes in these other 2 controllers:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(evt, cur, prev) {
    ...do what you have to do here, maybe set a $rootScope.path as you did
})
```

All using native Angular functionality. I actually do this in http://provok.in, a website I built using Angular, and I have a similar layout (well, not exactly, but I have "static" sections and an ng-view for the main content, dynamically updated based on the path, by the routeProvider).

Comment: The shortcoming I find with this there's no quick way to access $routeParams - you have to parse the URL yourself. I've used $routeProvider, with a dummy ng-view, and using the same controller on all routes, which gets passed the $routeParams. Now I just need to decide what to do - I tried to broadcast events, but came across the same problem as OP. Perhaps I should instead set properties on a shared service. Seems a bit long-winded though.