# AngularJS: "Global" menu buttons for multiple views

Tags: model-view-controller, angularjs

I've (very) recently dived into Angular, but I'm struggling a bit with how to design my layout.

For my site I've created a menu containing an input field and some buttons. The idea is that the input field combined with either of the buttons should service a function. So say for viewA, the input field should only act as a search bar. If the user however clicks one of the buttons the input field value should be used to as a basis to create a new item in another viewB.

The search function works great for viewA, but I'm unable to make the buttons switch views. I'm suspecting (or know, but don't know how to address it) this is because the mentioned buttons are outside the view (ng-view) and thus don't have a controller.

I've searched around for "multiple controllers / views", where suggestions vary from using the include function or create a service. Problem is I have no idea what would best practise or if it's even necessary for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu + input field is another view.  It should have its own controller.  Based on the route – `$on($routeChangeSuccess, ...)` – you can use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) to switch between the appropriate HTML/template in that view.  If your templates are large, you can use ng-include inside the ng-switch directives.  Otherwise don't bother, and just in-line the HTML inside each ng-switch-when.

For an example of how so use $routeChangeSuccess (but not ng-switch), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11910904/215945

Comment: Took me a while to understand the solution you suggested, but finally got it working. Thanks.

Comment: @KGChristensen, I tried to update the answer a bit.  Next time, feel free to ask for more clarification or examples if I'm being too terse.