# How do I show a block of HTML only on the index page with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a block of HTML that I only want to appear on the home page. How do I tell the view that this is the home page?

Here are some of my routes

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/index.html', 
        controller: App.Controllers.Index
    });
```

How can I use `ng-show` to figure out if I'm on the home page or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that "block of HTML" has its own view (and its own controller), you can listen for [$routeChangeSuccess](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route#$routeChangeSuccess) events, and update a $scope property that ng-show is bound to:

```
var BlockCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.showBlock = false;
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(evt, cur, prev) {
       if(...determine when you want to show the block...) {
           $scope.showBlock = true;
       } else {
           $scope.showBlock = false;
       }
    }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11910904/215945